# Python3: How do I update variables in a list using their index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
variable1 = 1
test_list = [variable1]
test_list[0] = 2
print(test_list[0]) #prints 2
print(variable1) #prints 1
```

This is a massive oversimplification of a larger problem I'm having in my other project, but it essentially boils down to this - how can update variables using the list index? I don't want to define variable1 explicitly, as I am trying to update multiple variables in a list using a for loop.

Comment: That's not how it works. To update `variable1` you assign to it, e.g. `variable1=1`. What problem do you have with the for loop?

Comment: One approach might be to contain your variables in a class as attributes and reassign to them.  Is this an option in your case?

Comment: for integers list doesn't keep information about `variable1`. it only keep value copied from `variable1`.

Comment: instead of variables `variable1 = 1`, `variable2 = 5`, `variable3 = 7`, etc. you should keep values on list `variable = [1, 5,7]` and useonly this list- ie use index to change it. `variable[0] = 9`, etc.

Comment: Describe the bigger problem.  There's likely a cleaner approach.

Comment: Adding to @pylang, this sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040); you're trying to make a bad solution work via kludges, missing the opportunity for a good solution that doesn't require ugly hacks.

Answer (score 4):

This would work more pythonically if you use a dictionary in place of list. Since dictionary keys can't be duplicated, you can use the key like a variable and the value like its value.

```
test_dict = {'variable1': 1, 'variable2': 2}
test_dict['variable1'] = 2

print(test_dict['variable1'])
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python primitives (int, boolean, float, etc.) and strings are immutable. And as a result, when you use their value, there is no reference to the variable left. Meaning that if you add them to a list, there is no relationship to the variable left so you can't change the original variable.

One solution is to store your variables themselves as lists:

```
variable1 = [1]
test_list = [variable1]
test_list[0][0] = 2
print(test_list[0]) #prints [2]
print(variable1) #prints [2]
```

Lists are mutable, so you can change the variables from the list.
Another is to use dictionaries keys as your 'variables', as Austin points out in his answer.